# How do I execute a Ruby 1.9.3 program from Windows Explorer on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ruby

I wrote a Ruby program that will check a `*.log` file for key words and phrases. The program is called "`Check_Log.rb`".

I use Windows 7 and I'd like to be able to right click the log file in Windows Explorer and execute the Ruby program.  Assuming a log file is called "`Test.log`", I'd like to be right click on it, choose "Check Log" from the menu and have Ruby execute the `Check_Log.rb` program as if it was executed from the command line like this:

```
ruby Check_Log.rb Test.log
```